# How to Never Retrieve Different Rows in a Changing Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit, offset

I have a table of millions of rows that is constantly changing(new rows are inserted, updated and some are deleted). I'd like to query 100 new rows(I haven't queried before) every minute but these rows can't be ones I've queried before. The table has a about 2 dozen columns and a primary key.

Happy to answer any questions or provide clarification.

Comment: By "new rows", do you mean new inserts or also updates?

Comment: @Gab Both, new inserts are made and old rows are updated constantly.

Comment: Yes but "I'd like to query 100 new rows", is that the inserts only or also the rows recently updated?

Comment: @Gab Just rows that I have not queried before, I don't care about if they've been updated recently or inserted recently. I only care whether or not I've queried them before.

Comment: I wrote a schema and answered your question.

Comment: Did my answer ended up solving your issue? If yes can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to have a separate table with just one row to store the last ID you fetched.

Let's say that's your "table of millions of rows":

```
-- That's your table with million of rows
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id serial unique,
    col1 text,
    col2 timestamp
);

-- Data sample
INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2)
SELECT 'test', generate_series
FROM generate_series(now() - interval '1 year', now(), '1 day');
```

You can create the following table to store an ID:

```
-- Table to keep last id
CREATE TABLE last_query (
  last_quey_id int references test_table (id)
);
-- Initial row
INSERT INTO last_query (last_quey_id) VALUES (1);
```

Then with the following query, you will always fetch 100 rows never fetched from the original table and maintain a pointer in `last_query`:

```
WITH last_id as (
    SELECT last_quey_id FROM last_query
), new_rows as (
    SELECT *
    FROM test_table
    WHERE id > (SELECT last_quey_id FROM last_id)
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 100
), update_last_id as (
    UPDATE last_query SET last_quey_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM new_rows)
)
SELECT * FROM new_rows;
```

Rows will be fetched by order of new IDs (oldest rows first).

Answer (score 1):

You basically need a unique, sequential value that is assigned to each record in this table. That allows you to search for the next X records where the value of this field is greater than the last one you got from the previous page.

Easiest way would be to have an identity column as your PK, and simply start from the beginning and include a "where id > @last_id" filter on your query. This is a fairly straightforward way to page through data, regardless of underlying updates. However, if you already have millions of rows and you are constantly creating and updating, an ordinary integer identity is eventually going to run out of numbers (a bigint identity column is unlikely to run out of numbers in your great-grandchildren's lifetimes, but not all DBs support anything but a 32-bit identity).

You can do the same thing with a "CreatedDate" datetime column, but as these dates aren't 100% guaranteed to be unique, depending on how this date is set you might have more than one row with the same creation timestamp, and if those records cross a "page boundary", you'll miss any occurring beyond the end of your current page.

Some SQL system's GUID generators are guaranteed to be not only unique but sequential. You'll have to look into whether PostgreSQL's GUIDs work this way; if they're true V4 GUIDs, they'll be totally random except for the version identifier and you're SOL. If you do have access to sequential GUIDs, you can filter just like with an integer identity column, only with many more possible key values.